# Jquery - passing a duplicate of a <div> to another

Tags: jquery, html

When passing the contents of a `<div>` to another `<div>` with jquery as below, the original is removed.
Is there a way to do this and still retain the original?
[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MYdc3/4/) - I want the document to read Item One, Item Two, Item One.

```
   function display() {
    $('#display').html($('#ItemOne'));
}

display();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('#display').html($('#ItemOne').html());
```

add .html()

Comment: I think OP wants the entire element (as far as I can tell). Using `.html()` would only append the content of `#ItemOne`. :o)

Comment: Actually the content is all I need (should have specified) so this works equally well.

Comment: +1 @jack - If the content is all you need, than this is actually better. Remember that if you use `.clone()` you're also cloning the ID, which means you'll have 2 items on the page with the same ID. This could cause problems. Using `.html()` as done here would take care of that issue.

Comment: After some playing around I realised as such.
Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 4):

use `clone()`

http://docs.jquery.com/Clone

```
function display() {
    $('#display').html($('#ItemOne').clone());
}

display();
```

Comment: This would work, but you should modify the ID if you're going to take this approach, so you don't end up with 2 elements with the same ID. Something like: `$('#ItemOne').clone().attr('id','cloned_content')`

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
function open() {
    $('#display').html($('#ItemOne').clone());
}
```

---

See: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYdc3/7/)